# Axios - Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

I was trying to figure out the problem on my own but it has been a pain in the a$$ trying to figure out. Im using axios and have no clue what seems to be causing the problem. (Im new to ReactJS) Below i've posted a screenshot if it will make is easier for you to determine the problem. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI83u.png)

```
export const actFetchMealsRequest = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return callApi('/Product', 'GET', null).then(res => {
            dispatch(GetAllMeal(res.data));
        });
    }
}

/*GET_ALL_MEAL*/
export function GetAllMeal(payload){
    return{
        type:'GET_ALL_MEAL',
        payload
    }
}
```

Comment: it says that you `res` is undefined . and you are trying to do `undefined.data` . Can you add the code of your `callApi`

Comment: I was able to solve the problem in the callApi, thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem it was in my callApi as @Shyam suggested,
this was my previous code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
let API_URL = 'https://5adc8779b80f490014fb883a.mockapi.io';
   export default function callApi(endpoint, method = 'GET', body) {
       return axios({
           method,
           url: `${API_URL}/${endpoint}`,
           data: body
       }).catch(err => {
           console.log(err);
       });
}
```

and this is the updated code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
let API_URL = 'https://5adc8779b80f490014fb883a.mockapi.io';
   export default async function callApi(endpoint, method = 'GET', body) {
       try {
           return axios({
               method,
               url: `${API_URL}/${endpoint}`,
               data: body
           });
       } catch (err) {
           console.log(err);
       }
}
```

I just converted to an async function.